# What happens to bin/debug folders once VB.NET project is published?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I've never published an application on VB.NET but am reaching the point where I'll be able to release it.

In my project I have a database using Access. Right now I understand I can go to bin/debug to open up the copy of the database that is copied over. My concern is will this database copy be accessible once I publish the project?

Comment: Nothing,  They are a developer/VS element and not part of the deployment

Comment: Thank you for your reponse!

Comment: If you are installing the app, the db ought to be in some `Users...` folder, for click once type things, the app and db get copied there.